# html spacing issue-Keep left margin as variable right margin 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the resolution 520-719px,earlier i kept the content fixed as 500px and kept margin:0 auto.So for a 700px screen,content would be 500px and margin left,right 100px each.
For 600px screen,content is 500px,margin left,right is 50 each.
Now,I want margin-left to be the same (screenWidth-500)/2 and margin right to be 0.The width of the center content wont be fixed anymore,it would be (500+whatever area of right margin)
How can I achieve this.Is this possible using css.??
I tried using jquery as when window size is from  520 to 719 px,I do calculations as margin-left=(screenWidth-500)/2 and margin-right:0
Please suggest a better solution.

Comment: Wow, that is really horrible to read. Please learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `calc`, like this:

( I used a wrapper to simulate a 600px window width - the red border)

```css
.your_div {
  width: calc(500px + ((100% - 500px) / 2));
  margin-left: calc((100% - 500px) / 2);
  margin-right: 0;
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="your_div"></div>
</div>
```